# How to use linked list to implement the multiplication of two polynomial in O(M^2N)?

Tags: c, algorithm, list, linked-list, polynomial-math

This is an exercise from "Data structure and algorithm analysis in C", exercise 3.7.
Assume there are two polynomials implemented in linked list. One has M terms. Another has N terms. The exercise ask me to implement the multiplication of two polynomial in O(M^2N)(Assume that M is the smaller one). How to solve this?

Comment: It would be better to show what code you have written so far and ask specific questions.

Comment: No, I mean the (square of M) times N.

Comment: The program is too long to paste here. But so far I wrote a multipication function which has O(MNlog(MN)) time complexity.  The idea is first use each term of polynomial A to multiply each term of polynomial B, then I will  get M*N new terms.  Then sort this M*N terms according to the term's exponent in the no-decreasing order.  The sorting algorithm I use is  merge sort. Then at last check through all the sorted terms to combine the terms with same exponent.

Comment: Sorry, I Forgot one requirment of the question. The answer of the multiplicaition must be sorted by terms' exponent in decreasing order.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the idea.

Suppose the polynomials are 1+x+x^3 and 1+x^2.

Create a linked list P using  (1,1)--->(1,1)--->(1,3)

Create another linked list Q  (1,1)--->(1,2) where (a,b) denotes coefficient of x^b.

Now for each node in P, multiply it with each node of Q.

How? we will create a node `res` with (x,y) where

`x= P->coeff * Q->coeff.`

And `y=P->exp+Q->exp`.

Add this new node to the polynomial which will contain the answer.

---

During insertion in the `answer` polynomial you have to keep in mind 2 things-

> i) Keep a sorted list (sorted against the exp)(increasing maybe as I have takem increasing here--you can take decreasing also).
>
> ii) Get the correct position in case you add new node and if a node with same exp value exists add the coeff only and delete the node that you are about to insert.

Ok! Now print the polynomial.

The complexity analysis.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have a question about your method. How can you guarantee your algorithm's complexity is O(M^2 * N)?

Answer (score 0):

You can find my implementation for polynomial multiplication [here](https://github.com/slavabro/multiplying-two-polynomials), which reads the polynomials from a file in the following format:
let's say 2X^5 + 3x^3 + 5X is a polynomial expression and its linked list representation is as follows:
 | 2 | 5  |  -|--->   | 3 | 4 |   -|---> |   5 | 1 | NULL|

Regarding the time complexity, I perform the multiplication by multiplying each term of the first polynomial by each term of the second, and than adding common terms (i.e. have the same degree) together.
If the first polynomial size is N and the second polynomial size is M, than by multiplying them term by term we get a complexity of N*M.
Pay attention that the output polynomial can be at most of size N+M (after adding together the common terms, so if you assume that M>N, and at each step of the terms multiplication you add a value to the cell which holds the same degree (if such exists, else you add a new cell), you can the desired complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! But I am still doubtful about the time complexity of your algorithm. I think that your complexity is O((N+M)*MN). The question required that the complexity should be O(M*M*N) and M is the smaller one between M and N.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that M < N.

Multiplying each term in the M terms' polynomial by the entire N terms' polynomial. Each step you will get an temporary result polynomial with N terms, then take the union of the result polynomial with this temp polynomial, which causes O(MN+N) in the last step.

Remind that there's O(MN) multiplications.
The union operations totally take O((N+N)+(2N+N)+(3N+N)+...+(MN+N))=O(M^2N).

So overall the complexity takes O(MN)+O(M^2N) = O(M^2N)

Comment: In addition, after MN multiplications you can use hash table to take the union of two polynomials, whose overall complexity can be O(MN).